# how to group user inputs for community based mapping app?

Tags: django, mongodb, geolocation

Me and a friend of mine are working on an app which gets input (map issues or some information user think it's worth sharing) from users for a specific location.

Our primary data is stored in mongodb. which has lat, long, address and zip code for each datapoint we have for the particular city.

> My question is:
>
> how to group multiple user inputs to the same
>   datapoint? for example a user can add some information about a place.
>   and another user can add similar info about the same place but from 2
>   blocks away. How do I group both inputs?

Any data-model or algorithm suggestions are welcome.

> PS: Framework we are using is Django

Comment: if you decide to choice PostgreSQL, you can use postgis for location/geometric queries.

Comment: thanks @levi, I'll check that out. only reason we choose mongo, because of it's geolocation support. so we could do queries like "near by" for particular geolocation. and mongo does it pretty fast

Comment: You can do that as well with postgis, but fine, the only issue is django plays nicer with postgis rather than mongo, but good luck.